# mySQL store data in a compressed format

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to store what's essentially log data in mySQL -- potentially large amounts of data in uncompressed form ( 25GB+ month ).

Each row consists of only two columns, a datetime column as a primary key, and a `data` column containing between 8k - 16k of uncompressed data.

I've attempted to use innoDB's `ROW_FORMAT=compressed` but it doesn't seem to have any actual effect on the size of the database. Using my sample data, its 0.53GB without using compressed row formatting, but its still 0.53GB using compressed row format.

I'm checking the size of the stored data with the following query (its in a test database so my test tables will always be the 'largest'):

```
SELECT CONCAT(table_schema, '.', table_name),
       CONCAT(ROUND(table_rows / 1000000, 2), 'M')                                    rows,
       CONCAT(ROUND(data_length / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G')                    DATA,
       CONCAT(ROUND(index_length / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G')                   idx,
       CONCAT(ROUND(( data_length + index_length ) / ( 1024 * 1024 * 1024 ), 2), 'G') total_size,
       ROUND(index_length / data_length, 2)                                           idxfrac
FROM   information_schema.TABLES
ORDER  BY data_length + index_length DESC
LIMIT  10;
```

Comment: Have you tried measuring consumption by looking at the disk space consumed in the mysqld server's file system?  Keep in mind that disk space is by far the cheapest asset in a server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ARCHIVE` storage engine may do what you want.  It's a special engine that stores rows in a compressed flat file format.  It's best for write-once read-infrequently use because it's not indexed.  But it's very fast and very space-efficient.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/archive-storage-engine.html

Comment: the archive storage engine doesn't allow for any indexes - not even a primary key. This data would need to be accessed fairly regularly and would not be a good candidate for an archive table. This table would not be a stable size until about 15M rows -- and any kind of regular selects against it would be brutal

Comment: Correct, ARCHIVE is useless if you need to random-access the data.